# Set Default Value for binding combobox from json

Tags: c#, json, uwp, combobox

I have a combobox whose items are taken from json on the server. I want to set the default value of the combobox to be "Pendidikan Moral"  (which is the 6th index)

XAML:

```
<ComboBox   
    x:Name="serialBox"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind SerialList}"
        PlaceholderText="Pilih Serial"
        SelectionChanged="SerialBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Code:

```
List<Serial> SerialList = new List<Serial>();    
try
                    {
                        string urlPath = "https://mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/Fetch/serial";
                        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
                        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                        {
                        };
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt");
                        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        try
                        {
                            JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                            JsonArray jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();
                            foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData)
                            {
                                JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue.GetObject();
                                string id = groupObject1["id"].GetString();
                                string name = groupObject1["nama"].GetString();

                                Serial serial = new Serial();
                                serial.ID = id;
                                serial.Name = name;

                                SerialList.Add(new Serial()
                                {
                                    ID = serial.ID,
                                    Name = serial.Name
                                });
                            }
                            serialBox.SelectedIndex = 6;
                        }
```

Serial.cs

```
class Serial
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }
```

From the code above I have a problem, which appears an error message like the image below:
[image: error message]

How to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Is your SerialList implements ObservableCollection? This collection knows how to notify UI. So, one more point. x:Bind is bind to code behind classes. SerialList is field of code behid? Or part of ViewModel?

One more point: you run asink operation. But XAML renders in the same time when it's created. You should set SerialList in constructor. Becouase when you start operation, XAML is renders in parallel thread. So, it can faced with null reference exception. Because it is not loaded.

Comment: serialList is a list for serialBox

Comment: Could you show full code of code behind (*.xaml.cs file) and view model.

Comment: In the post above I have added the serial.cs class and serialList

Comment: You add not full code of class. It's imposible to find out the problem. In your examle you create List<Serial> SerialList = new List<Serial>();    

It is not Propperty of class. It's variable. For binding you need a property.

Comment: Add something like this in your class:

public List<Serial> SerialList {get;set;} = new List<Serial>();

Comment: The code above is full code for retrieving data from json into the combobox

Comment: Data from JSON is not important. You have a problem with XAML.

Comment: The code above successfully retrieved data from json, but I had a problem setting the default value of the combobox to "pendidikan moral" (6th index of the combox)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204520/discussion-between-tematre-and-rose).